# HOWTO: auto increment primary key?

Tags: smart-contract, multi-index, table

How do we do this in EOSIO multi_index table? Want to define a table with an auto increment primary key id.

Answer (score 7):

Have a look to [available_primary_key](https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.6.0/group__multiindex.html#function-availableprimarykey) in the EOS documentation, multi indexes do support auto increment keys.

Comment: Please update the link, current one is not working.

Comment: https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eosio.cdt/latest/classeosio_1_1multi__index/#function-available_primary_key

Answer (score 1):

The two answers to this question are links to external sites that are now broken. this is why answers that are links are frowned upon, links break and therefore your answer breaks. to actually auto increment the primary key say your multi index uses a `uint64_t` as its id. When emplacing into the table set the id like so.

`row.column_name = table_name.available_primary_key();`

Answer (score 0):

You check the way monstereos did. They have table st_pet_config define last_id start with 0 and everytime you create new pet last_id increase https://github.com/leordev/monstereos/blob/master/contracts/pet/pet.hpp#L85

Comment: Doing it this way is obsolete.